# Heroku + Node + NestJs H13 Error "Connection closed without response"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I just spent several hours getting SSL working on my free heroku deploy. Locally everything works fine, I can `GET localhost:3000` and get back `"Hello World"` but my heroku deploy just returns `"Application Error"` (using either `http` or `https`):

```
2020-11-08T21:22:28.066978+00:00 app[web.1]: [32m[Nest] 33   - [39m11/08/2020, 9:22:28 PM   [38;5;3m[NestApplication] [39m[32mNest application successfully started[39m[38;5;3m +7ms[39m

2020-11-08T21:22:28.507341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

2020-11-08T21:22:30.593116+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=<app_name>.herokuapp.com request_id=af5f5b81-2320-4567-9094-79dc17f7d579 fwd="73.243.1.198" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

My main.ts looks like this:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
    let app: INestApplication;
    if (process.env.MODE === 'PROD') {
        let httpsOptions = {
            key: process.env.SSL_KEY.replace('"', '').replace("'", ''),
            cert: process.env.SSL_CERT.replace('"', '').replace("'", ''),
        };
        app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { httpsOptions });
    } else {
        app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    }

    app.enableCors();
    await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}
bootstrap().catch(console.error);
```

and I have a top level api set up like this

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
    constructor() {}

    @Get()
    getBase() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

the env seems to be getting mapped in properly. If the `PORT` wasn't being bound then heroku would crash anyways.

If I run `ping https://<app_name>.herokuapp.com/` I get

```
ping: cannot resolve https://<app_name>.herokuapp.com/: Unknown host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somehow I didn't need the `httpsOptions` with how I did SSL, so just `app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);` will work